# Existence/continuity of Jacobian matrix and partial derivatives

Tags: analysis

I'm working through an appendix for Differential Geometry which summarizes some elementary results in analysis, but I can't seem to find a clarification for the following theorem on the internet:

$F:U\subset \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^3 $ has a $\mathbb{continuous}$ derivative iff $D_1F,...,D_mF$ exist and are continuous

I understand existence and continuity of the partial derivatives is necessary for the Jacobian matrix to be the derivative, but I don't see why they guarantee that the derivative will be continuous. Conversely, I understand that existence of the derivative implies existence of the partial derivatives, but I can't see why they must be continuous

Comment: The Jacobian is a matrix, and every matrix-valued function is continuous if and only if each entry is a continuous scalar-valued function. This is a basic property of the space of matrices, which is finite-dimensional.

Comment: And for the converse?

Comment: What do you mean, which converse? The Jacobian matrix can exist and not be continuous. In this case, some partial derivative is not continuous. Is this what you are referring to?

Comment: Yes, I wanted that confirmed. Thanks a lot!

Comment: If I wanted to do a change of variable in an integration do I require the Jacobian to be continuous ?